# Adjust geom_bar plot to show all elements

Tags: r

I use geom_bar to plot,my code is like this:

```
ggplot(top_pathway, aes(y = NES, x = pathway)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), stat = "identity", fill = "blue") + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

However, when I do not use the coord_flip, the figure part can be showed but the labels are condensed at the bottom and cannot be read.
[image]

But when I added the the "coord_flip", the figure part is gone, like this:
[image]

My question is there a solution to show both label and figure as this:

[image]

Thanks a lot~~!

Comment: Make your window wider? Or if you're saving the graph, make the width wider in save command.

Comment: You can also reduce the font size, use the `base_size` argument of `theme_bw(base_size = 10)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks so much, I try to adjust the number of base_size, and finally it works~~~!